# How can i change the default user table in auth laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I need to change the Auth default table to another table. I'm using Laravel 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit in `config\auth.php` to change default `auth` model
you can refer this [change default auth](https://www.5balloons.info/changing-authentication-table-laravel/) for reference

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by editing `config\auth.php` around line 65

```
   'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'ANOTHER_TABLE',
        ],
```